# How to print array from axios in vue?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Response data from axios is an array,like this:

[image]

How can i print the data without the ['']?
I tried v-for but it doesn't work(it prints the array with spaces between the letters)

```
             <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">[[ title ]]</h5>
                <p class="card-text"><b><mark><em>Start Date:</em></mark></b> [[start_date]] <br> <b><mark><em>End Date:</em></mark></b> [[end_date]] <br> <b>
                <em>Cinema:</em></b> [[cinema]] <br> <b><em>Category:</em></b> <br>[[category]]</p>
                <div class="row">
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular way to render data would be using curly-brackets like: `{{var}}`

You can check more here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

In order to iterate array elements you could use the `v-for` directive.

For example:
`<template v-for="user in users">`
`{{user}}`
`</template>` would eventually printout the data without (brackets) [ ]

Comment: yep, but i use django along with vue, so i changed delimiters to [[ ]]

Comment: stating it somewhere would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. using vue html directive

```html
Category:</em></b> <br><span v-for="cat in category" :key="cat">[[cat]]</span></p>
```

2. or you can do it right in javascript using `join()` statement:

```html
Category:</em></b> <br>[[category.join(', ')]]</p>
```

Comment: second option is probably faster and cleaner in your case.
first option is if you'd like to use some further beautification. Like putting categories into `v-chip`s

Comment: I replaced ' ' with " " , after i applied your second solution and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my api response using '' and no "". The trick is to replace '' with "" `this.categor= this.categor.replace(/'/g, '"')` and after parse the results:

```
this.categor=JSON.parse(this.categor)
```